# Lebesgue integral over subset

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a basic question related to Lebesgue integration restricted to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. In general, for $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a measurable space, if $f$ is measurable one can calculate the integral restricted to a measurable subset $E$ as $$\int_{E}fd\mu=\int_{X}f\mathcal X_E d\mu$$

Now, suppose $X=\mathbb R^n$, is $$\int_E f(x+v)dx=\int_{X} f(x+v) \mathcal X_{E}(x+v)dx$$ or $$\int_E f(x+v)dx=\int_{X} f(x+v) \mathcal X_{E}(x)dx \space \space ?$$ I am really confused by this, if anyone could explain which equality holds and why I would really appreciated it.

Comment: Could you explain why you have a translation vector $v$ in the function $f$? Also on both the second and third equation, the integral should be over $X$ on the right hand side : $\int_X\ldots dx$. 
Finally, my guess is that the last formula is what you need.

Comment: It is the second one : for $g\left(x\right):=f\left(x+v\right)$, we have
$\int_Eg\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}\mu\left(x\right)$ $=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g\left(x\right)\mathcal X_{E}\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}\mu\left(x\right)$.